# How do I stop this table front stretching Gmail when it works in Outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail

I'm creating an HTML email signature for Outlook. I've created the code and added it to my signature, but I'm running into an issue. The simple black square I'm trying to create gets distorted. It's a 3x3 table where ever cell should be 15px. But it is obviously getting squished.

Here's what's happening (the black table should be a perfect square. It works in Outlook, but not Gmail.

[image: demonstration]

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
body, p, table, tr, td{
    font-size:1px; line-height:1px;border-spacing:0;
}

.MsoNormal{
    font-size:1px; line-height:1px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
body, p, table, tr, td{
    font-size:1px; line-height:1px;border-spacing:0;
}

.MsoNormal{
    font-size:1px; line-height:1px
}
</style>
<p>
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background:#ffffff;border:0px;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="45" style="background:border:0px;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
            <table align="left" width="45" height="45" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;border:0px;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;">
                <tr style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
                    <td width="15" height="15" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: p1x; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
                    <td width="15" height="15" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15" style="color: transparent; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: transparent;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15" bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">
                    <td width="15" height="15"bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15"bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                    <td width="15" height="15"bgcolor="#000000" style="color: #000000; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;width:15px; height:15px;border-spacing:0;"><span style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="10" style="background:border:0px;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:1px; line-height:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><p style="color: #1a1a1a; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 15px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px;"><b>John Jenkins</b>
            <br />Consultant, Jenkins Consulting, LLC
            <br />325.552.9836 (w)&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:john.jenkins@jenkconsult.com" style="color: #1a1a1a;">john.jenkins@jenkconsult.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.jenkconsult.com" style="color: #1a1a1a;">http://www.jenkconsult.com</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML interpretation is completely up to the web client you are viewing it in as well as the browser's engine. In short, it's a nightmare to try to find a standard way that things are interpreted, since every webmail client has different rules and support, and every browser will display it differently.

Your best bet is to use an image for the squares and HTML format the rest as seen. Otherwise things *will* look different depending if the email is sent to a GMail, Yahoo, Live etc.

https://www.email-standards.org/clients/

Particularly check out the 'Gmail' portion.

Also, some good reading about HTML/CSS support in webclients and desktop clients:

http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Comment: I've considered using images, but they are a pain for Outlook users. I was looking for a way of creating the same graphic without having to rely on the image. I'll check out the email standards links.